# is + past participle vs. has been + past participle?

Tags: modal-verbs, past-participles

What is the difference between these two sentences?

> After the source code **is** deployed, please check if there are any bugs.
>
> After the source code **has been** deployed, please check if there are any bugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only "has been" infers *completion*, and for that reason, I prefer it in your example, because you can only move to the next step *after* deployment is complete.

*Deployment* is a process. I don't know how long your particular deployment takes - it may be instantaneous - but let's say you are pushing out some software or a software update across a network. You might say that deployment begins when you run the command, but deployment is only completed when all machines on the network have received and applied the update. You would want to check that the deployment had worked *after* it had pushed out, not seconds after it began.

"After the source code *is* deployed" could refer to that initial first step of authorising the deployment. For this reason, I prefer:

> After the source code *has been* deployed, please check if there are any bugs.

Answer (score 2):

1. "is" refers to the state of the source code. Therefore, "deployed" is the *state* of the source code.
2. "has been" refers to an action that has happened to the source code. Therefore, "deployed" is *something that has happened* to the source code.

They mean the same thing, though, practically. Either way, bugs should be checked *after* the source code is deployed. Something most software developers would not like. :)